# angular js nested controllers list/item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and wanted advice on the best route to achieve something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dreadjr/2sfJz/15/).  This jsFiddle doesn't work but here is the idea.

I want tabs along the top with items available for selection.  When you select the item, the data is populated below.

I wanted to have a ListController and an ItemController, so i can separate out the methods that act on the list vs that act on the item; since i wanted the items to be updatable directly.  I am getting all the data on the page load, so i don't want to load each tab dynamically.

How can i do this and/or how can i fix the fiddle or new fiddle?
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreadjr/2sfJz/15/)
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/86DoOQdakQ8ijJAzaIZa)

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ListController">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li ng-repeat="artist in list">
        <a show-tab="" ng-href="" ng-click="select(artist)">{{$index}} - {{artist.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-controller="ItemController">
      <p>{{name}} - {{selected.name}}</p>
      <span>{{totalSongs}}</span>
      <span>{{selected.songs.length}}</span>

      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="song in selected.songs" ng-controller="ItemController">{{song}} - {{totalSongs}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would really like to keep the controllers separate and logic separate.

Comment: The jsfiddle seems to work exactly according to your description. Could you explain what is not working in more detail?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: That's funny, the question matches exactly mine and the problem is actually the good answer :p

Answer (score 4):

I created some functionality in the ItemController to illustrate how you could act on them separately:
http://jsfiddle.net/jdstein1/LbAcz/

Added some data to the list controller:

```
$scope.list = [{
    name: "Beatles",
    songs: [{
        title: "Yellow Submarine",
        time: "424"
    }, {
        title: "Helter Skelter",
        time: "343"
    }, {
        title: "Lucy in the Sky with Diamonds",
        time: "254"
    }]
}, {
    name: "Rolling Stones",
    songs: [{
        title: "Ruby Tuesday",
        time: "327"
    }, {
        title: "Satisfaction",
        time: "431"
    }]
}];
```

And fleshed out the item controller:

```
app.controller('ItemController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectItem = function (song) {
        $scope.song.time++;
    };
}]);
```